# Avoid new record race conditions with FOR UPDATE

Tags: apex, asynchronous, locking, for-update

Under simple circumstances `FOR UPDATE` does only respect records that existed when the query was executed. But I need all available records matching my query when the transaction proceeds.

Let me explain my problem with this simple query:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account FOR UPDATE];
```

1. Imagine `transaction A` is waiting for another `transaction B` to release the records but this `transaction B` also **inserts new records** matching your query.
2. `transaction B` finishes - The requested records get released.
3. `transaction A` get's notified and checks for changes on the requested records.

   - optionally runs query again if changes to the subset were detected.
   - **does not apply when only new records matching the query were added**.
4. `transaction A` runs it's logic only on a subset of records (excluding the new records).

First I expected `FOR UPDATE` to be smart enough, on the other hand I technically understand why it isn't. But the fact, that it works as expected as soon as any requested record registers a change, makes it kind of unreliable and might produce unexpected results frequently.

This is my current solution to solve these scenarios, but I'm tired of introducing extra queries since they are a rare resource on the platform.

```
List<Account> locked = [SELECT Id FROM Account FOR UPDATE]; // Lock the existing once
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];          // re-query all including new
```

**Is there any feature/workaround, that helps me avoiding these extra queries?
Or should we even request Salesforce to make FOR UPDATE more reliable?**

---

I used this component to test the FOR UPDATE behaviour, clicking the button multiple times in a second:

test.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-button onclick={handleClick} label="create new account"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button onclick={reset} label="reset"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

test.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import insertAccount from "@salesforce/apex/TestCtrl.insertAccount";
import reset from "@salesforce/apex/TestCtrl.reset";

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    handleClick() {
        insertAccount();
    }
    reset() {
        reset();
    }
}
```

TestCtrl.cls

```
public with sharing class TestCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void insertAccount() {
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Foo%' FOR UPDATE];
        System.debug(accounts);

        insert new Account(Name='Foo');


        /* example for working scenario
        for(Account a : accounts) {
            a.Name = a.Name+'o';
        }
        update accounts;
        */
    }


    @AuraEnabled
    public static void reset() {
        delete [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Foo%'];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're creating / expecting new records "later" in a transaction, then it seems like you'll need an extra SOQL query anyhow.  I think if you gave a more concrete example, the community would be able to offer up some good advice

Comment: @BrianMiller I just added my "test environment" :)

Comment: Can you explain the actual business logic here? You want to lock the ENTIRE Account object until one insert transaction is completed? You want to prevent two different users from inserting substantially the same Account at the same time? More details would help.

Comment: @CharlesT I implemented a duplicate validation. it merges records and decides whether to keep the existing or replace it with a new one. But as soon is I oversee some records, duplicates make it into the database. The entire account lock is just to explain the problem the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

`FOR UPDATE` does include records that are still in the insert process (and deletes, too!), not just updates. The locking statement basically forces the code to wait until any pending DML operations complete. However, you do need to specify it for each operation. In your example code, the delete code is *not* using record locks, so it can miss records. You should always use record locks if you expect there may be race conditions:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void reset() {
    delete [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Foo%' FOR UPDATE];
}
```

---

Edit: I just realized that what's being observed is likely because of the [boxcar effect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_background_actions.htm). Rapidly pushing buttons in Lightning causes actions to be batched together, such that "transaction A" will complete before "transaction B" starts. You would need to test with multiple users/browsers in order to fully test the effect of record locking when using Lightning.

Comment: the reset button is not part of the problem, it's just there to clear the database for further testing

Comment: @Basti You might also be experiencing the boxcar effect. Basically, your test is flawed, in that multiple actions in short order in Lightning are batched together. While you may think that A and B are running simultaneously, they are in fact running one after the other.

Comment: Not sure if I want to change this behaviour. All I need is multiple interactions with the database where no apex transaction completes before the next one started. I achieved this with the button and it was visible, that they all thought there are no entries yet. So in fact they are not running one after each other, cause if so, they would have logged different results, or am I missing something? Try the above example, press the button 4 times and all the transactions think the database is empty.